# Inter OS communication for AMP setup

Tags: ipc

i am building a system were 2 different OS run on the same multicore device. both OS run completely independent each owning part of the memory an I/O. however they need to communicate with each other both for control and data. since data volumes may be large communication should be based on shared memory and not on network I/F.

i need to use an inter processor communication method that is OS independent and based on shared memory for high bandwiths.

instead of implementing my own protocol im looking for some standard protocol. i have seen some protocols under the catoegory of inter process communication (IPC) but i am not sure if they are OS indepedent or if even if they work when the communicating processes are members of 2 different instances of the same OS type.

what about the POSIX IPC protol ? can that work ?
http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/V2_chap02.html#tag_15_07

Comment: I'm not sure if this is possible without some level of networking between the two OS's. Both need access to the same location obviously, so both will need to know exactly where that location is. Great question though.